# Return multiple values from a function using mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, arrays

How do I return multiple values from the array returned from mysqli_fetch_assoc() in the code below?

```
        function db_query($sql){
            $con = db_connect();
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            return $result;
        }

        function db_select($sql){  
            $rows = array();
            $result = db_query($sql);
                if(!$result){
                    return false;
                }
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $CID = $row['C_ID'];
                    $Fname = $row['C_Fname'];
                    $rows = $CID;
                }
            return $rows;
        }       
    
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
             echo $rows=db_select("SELECT C_ID,C_Fname FROM Customer WHERE C_Email='$Email'")
           //how to also return $Fname?
        }
```

Comment: you can return $row instead of $rows. Means, you can return array value instead of one string value(C_ID).

Comment: Thank you all for your help and clear explanations. They all worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db_select function returns a full array it looks like, so likely you are wanting to access those two variables like so:

```
function db_select($sql){  
    $rows = array();
    $result = db_query($sql);
        if(!$result){
            return false;
        }

        // This function could potentially return multiple rows...
        while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            // This will return multiple rows
            $row[] = $array;
        }

        // This will return only one row
        // (but there may be more that you are missing)
    //  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)

    // Notice change here
    return $row;
}       

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $rows = db_select("SELECT C_ID,C_Fname FROM Customer WHERE C_Email='$Email'")

     // If you have the one row option you echo like so
 //     echo $rows['C_ID'];
 //     echo $rows['C_Fname'];

     // For multiple row option, do a foreach or if you know the key you can access it directly
     foreach($rows as $arrays) {
             echo $arrays['C_ID'];
             echo $arrays['C_Fname'];
         }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php):

> A function can not return multiple values, but similar results can be obtained by returning an array.

See also the example #2 in the documentation.

In your case, you could just `return $row;`. However, from your code you are trying to gather the result of multiple rows. This example gathers all individual rows in the array `$rows`:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}
return $rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function db_select($sql){  
        $rows = array();
        $result = db_query($sql);
        if(!$result){
            return false;
         }else{
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            return $row;
         }
}  

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $rows = db_select("SELECT C_ID,C_Fname FROM Customer WHERE C_Email='$Email'")
     echo $rows['C_ID'];
     echo $rows['C_Fname'];
}
```