# How to generate email trigger to specific email when particular field in database is entered

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, email, triggers

i was hoping to get some assistance.

I want to send an email notification to a specific customer email when a specific field has data put into it.

I have built a form in which a customer is redirected to a paypal page, at this point, the user's info is inputted into a database.

I am then able to edit the info on a an admin webpage where all the info is being echoed from the database. The field i want to update is named "shippingnumber" which is blank upon the customers submission. When we enter a number into this field, i want it to generate an email which would then be sent to the email associated in the same line, informing them there order has been shipped etc, in this case for example "wendybrown@hotmail.com. Below is a link to a picture of my database being echoed to a webpage from the mysql database, circled in red is the field i would like to input a number, and circled in blue is the email i need to receive the email notification once the shippingnumber field is inputted with a number

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaZ1e.png)

I have done some research into this matter and have tried it myself,but im not able to figure this out and have not been able to find a solution that works for my needs. Please forgive me as i am new to this and was hoping to get some guidance on how to achieve this. Below is the html page with my paypalform, in this case the product is worth $325.

Thank You

HTML:

```
<form action="PPPaymentForm/PPPaymentForm.php"  method="post" name="topchoiceform" id="topchoiceform">
    <input placeholder="Company Name" type="text" name="companyname" required>
    <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="firstname" required>
    <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="lastname" required>
    <input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" required>
    <input placeholder="Address" type="text" name="address" required>
    <input name="shipping" class="shipping" type="checkbox" id="shipping" value="19.99"/>
    <label class="shippingcheck">19.99(Optional Shipping, will be added to total if choosen)</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Pay Now</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwtablename" id="hdwtablename" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwppproductname" id="hdwppproductname" value="Bronze Plan 325">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwppamount" id="hdwppamount" value="325">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwppcurrency" id="hdwppcurrency" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwpplanguage" id="hdwpplanguage" value="en_US">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwok" id="hdwok" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwemail" id="hdwemail" value="something+gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwnook" id="hdwnook" value="http://">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwactivation_email" id="hdwactivation_email" value="email">
    <input type="hidden" name="plan" id="plan" value="$325">
    <input type="hidden" name="shippingchoosen" id="shippingchoosen" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="shippingnumber" id="shippingnumber" value="">
  </form>
```

---

Hey Mascaliente
Thanks for responding. Im using a script from hotdreamweaver scripts called paypal payment form.(www.hotdreamweaver.com/paypal-payment-form) So the way it works is that the html form thats located in the page is converted into a paypal form, which generates a folder called "PPPaymentForm/PPPaymentForm.php  Below is a link to a notepad document with the php.

http://www.cedarpublishing.com/phpcode.txt

### UPDATED

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die ("Cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("database") or die("Cannot select database");


  /*SECTION 2*/

    /*
     * Checks form field for shipping number, then where shipping has email, send email to recipient     

     */

     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
     $shippingnumber = $_POST['shippingnumber'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];


     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0)
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $shippingnumber = $row['shippingnumber'];
    if(isset($_POST['shippingnumber'])==$row['shippingnumber']){



       $to = $_POST['email'];
       $first = $_POST['firstname'];
       $last = $_POST['lastname'];
       $subject = "Product has been shipped";
       $subject .= $last; 
       $subject .= ', ';
       $subject .= $first;
       $subject .= ')';

       $message .= 'Company Name: ' . $_POST['companyname'];
       $message = 'First Name: ' . $_POST['firstname'] . "\r\n\r\n";
       $message .= 'Last Name: ' . $_POST['lastname'] . "\r\n\r\n";
       $message .= 'Address Line 1: ' . $_POST['address'] . "\r\n\r\n";
       $message .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n\r\n";



       $headers = "From: myownemail@gmail.com\r\n";
       $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';


$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($email) {
    $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: $email";
}

$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

}


/*SECTION 3*/

    /*
     * Checks if the shipping number exists and look for email in that row which belongs to that shipping number to send email out.
     */



    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM topchoiceform WHERE shippingnumber = '$shippingnumber' AND '$shippingnumber' MATCHES $email";



$result = mysql_query($sql)or die('Could not find member: ' . mysql_error());

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($shippingnumber = $row['shippingnumber']){
             echo "It exists";
}            
    }else{
        echo "No matching shipping number found upon sql call";

    }

?>
```

Comment: You need to describe your code a little better as in this case the HTML doesn't help us very much. What I can see you're submitting this HTML document to a PHP page, can we take a look at that? Any email sending needs to be done on the server side.

Comment: Hey Mascaliente Thanks for responding. Im using a script from hotdreamweaver scripts called paypal payment form.(www.hotdreamweaver.com/paypal-payment-form) So the way it works is that the html form thats located in the page is converted into a paypal form, which generates a folder called "PPPaymentForm/PPPaymentForm.php Below is a link to a notepad document with the php.

http://www.cedarpublishing.com/phpcode.txt

Comment: @MannySmith - please stop trying to edit the answer with updated code. That should be added into the _question_, not someone's answer.

Comment: Hi andrewsi, my apologies, its my first time using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die ("Cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("database") or die("Cannot select database");


  /*SECTION 2*/

    /*
     * Checks form field for shipping number, then where shipping has email, send email to recipient     

     */

     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
     //$shippingnumber = $_POST['shippingnumber']; dont assign this value yet
     //$email = $_POST['email']; assign this after you check to see if $_POST is set

    //You can do this two proven ways....one is to get 1 result with the proper query. The other to loop through the records in the database to check for the number.
     //here it loops through all the records

     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         $array;
         $shippingnumber = $row['shippingnumber'];
         $email = $_POST['email'];
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            // This will return multiple rows
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701305/return-multiple-values-from-a-function-using-mysqli-fetch-assoc
            if($row['shippingnumber'] == $shippingnumber){
                //record containing the shipping number is found.
                $array[] = $row;
            }
        }

       $to = $array['email']; // email = the name of the column in your database. 
       $first = $_POST['firstname'];
       $last = $_POST['lastname'];
       $subject = "Product has been shipped";
       $subject .= $last; 
       $subject .= ', ';
       $subject .= $first;
       $subject .= ')';

       $message .= 'Company Name: ' . $_POST['companyname'];
       $message = 'First Name: ' . $_POST['firstname'] . "\r\n\r\n";
       $message .= 'Last Name: ' . $_POST['lastname'] . "\r\n\r\n";
       $message .= 'Address Line 1: ' . $_POST['address'] . "\r\n\r\n";
       $message .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n\r\n";

       $headers = "From: myownemail@yourdomain.com\r\n"; 
       ////email on your domain. NOT SURE if you even need an email...
       ////but headers are touchy, Usually web based applications can only operate WITHIN its own DOMAIN
       $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';


$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($email) {
    $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: $email";
}

$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

}


/*SECTION 3*/

    //NOTE: This is basically what we did in part 1 without sending anything except were finding the shipping number exactly as it is in the databse and pulling the whole record(all columns)

    /*
     * Checks if the shipping number exists and look for email in that row which belongs to that shipping number to send email out.
     */


    //this isnt going to work,
    //$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM topchoiceform WHERE shippingnumber = '$shippingnumber' AND '$shippingnumber' MATCHES $email";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM topchoiceform WHERE shippingnumber = '$shippingnumber'"; 
//select one record where the shipping number matches
//now you dont need to loop this time

//$result = mysql_query($sql)or die('Could not find member: ' . mysql_error());

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){ //if this is > 0 than the shippingnumber exists
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($shippingnumber == $row['shippingnumber']){
             //echo "It exists";
             $email = $row['email']; 
             $firstname = $row['firstname'];
             $lastname = $row['lastname'];
             //ect...remember the names inside $row['name'] is the same thing in your database

             //enter code to send mail
}            
    }else{
        echo "No matching shipping number found upon sql call";

    }

?>
```

Comment: I filled in some blanks for you, I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Jack, its looking good so far. However, we actually don't  need to generate a number. When the form is processed, we actually want the shippingnumber field to be blank. We will actually be receiving the shippingnumber from fedex or ups after the customer has made their payment. When we get that number, then we would fill that shippingorder field with that number. Which would then send the email to that particular customer. So for the html part, would i just use my previous html code?

Comment: Hey Jack, unfortunately i was not able to receive an email when i entered in a number into the shippingnumber field. I have outlined in detail the issues i am having above in the code. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: Did you create the email you're sending from in your cpanel?

Comment: Hi Jack

Nope, the email is already created in gmail(thisisatestemail2016@gmail.com) So when the user submits it in the order form, it is inputted into the field named "email". So then when i entered in a number into the field "shippingorder" it would send the email notification to thisisatestemail2016@gmail.com

Comment: As an example, if you were to enter in your own credentials, and you used your email in the order form (eg: jackdaniels@something.com), you then would be in the database, at this point, i would want to enter a number into the "shippingorder" field in the same row, at that point you would get the email notification. at  jackdaniels@something.com

Comment: Write a script that sends an email...see if that works...then go from there.

Comment: Hi Jack, i wrote a script in section 2 of the php code that should send an email alert to the email address that was submitted in the order form when data is entered into the shippingorder field for that very same person in the row, however no such luck, i enter in the data into the empty shippingorder field, and no email alert.  I updated the code in my question if you wouldnt mind taking a look at. Thanks:)

Comment: Hey Jack, are you still able to help?:)

Comment: Possibly. I think you're on the right track, at least. Answer is updated to fix your new codes syntax and some minor logic.

Comment: Good job Manny, I knew you could do it.